# data files in an application

Tags: c#

We have data files which are encrypted in our wpf app.
We would like to save in a location where the user will not be aware just to avoid any modifications/tampering in any way. 
The datafiles are of sizes nearly 100MB and some of them are zipfiles.
One thought is storing them in IsolatedFileStorage but it looks like it only allows to save strings in txt and due to the size being too large there seems to be issues saving them.
Another thought is save them in the same folder where the program runs from but set the hidden attributes so they are not visible. Just wondering if you have any suggestions.
Thanks
N

Comment: if they are encrypted why do you want to hide them from the user?

Comment: Even though the consensus will probably favor NOT hiding, it's a valid question and the proper answer (and discussion) needs exposure. +1

Comment: I am using simple encryption and it may be possible to decrpt it. So i am hiding.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, I would hide them and bury them deep inside the user profile (`%USERPROFILE%`) or application data (`%APPDATA%`) directories.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any methods in C#/Wpf which give us access to read & write to these folders. Also do we need to worry about giving permissions to these folders for reading & writing.
Thanks

Comment: If people are going to mark my answer down, it'd be courteous at least to leave a comment. The question wasn't about "the moral implications of" - it requested advice and I gave it. If my advice is incorrect, technically, then please tell me why.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping files invisible from the user is maybe not a good idea. After all its his machine and he might want to know where his discspace is going. If the files are zip maybe you can put a password on them.

Comment: I agree.  It is the user's machine, not yours.  Further, given that you're apparently just hiding the files and encrypting them with a key /on the user's machine/, I fail to see what you're really achieving.  Security through obscurity never works.

Comment: Imagine you are storing the files somewhere in C: drive hidden from the user. Now user might format or re-install the OS on the same drive. As a result he has lost all these files because he never knew where the files were stored. So best approach is to look for better encryption and tell the user where the default location of the files are.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the isolated storage functions

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IsolatedStorage.aspx

You can encrypt the files before writing them into storage using a CrpytoStream.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/using_cryptostream.aspx